# Initialize variiable with the type in a variable

Tags: java

```
public void initialize(Class<? extends MyType> type)
{
   MyType variable = new type();
}
```

That doesn't work.
How can I do it?

-siiikooo

Comment: Read the javadoc for `Class`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

You can call [newInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) like this -

```
public void initialize(Class<? extends MyType> type) {
    try {
        MyType variable = type.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an other way in which i can call a constructor with parameters?

Comment: @user3224044 Yes. Post another question if you get stuck, but you can start with [java.lang.reflect.Constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the newInstance() method of Class object.

for above example you can do:

type.newInstance();

The limitation on for this approach is you can't call constructor that has parameters.

Comment: That's my problem the constructor has some Parameters :(